# Log In Error I cant log in with multiple users while my system can create many users

Tags: php, html, sql, database

[image: administration]

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    include("conn.php");
    $qry=mysql_query("Select * from tblru");
    $qry2=mysql_query("Select * from tbladmin");
    $credentials=mysql_fetch_array($qry);
    $credentials2=mysql_fetch_array($qry2);
    if(isset($_POST['login'])){

                    if($_POST['user']==$credentials["user"]){
                        if($_POST['pass']==$credentials["pass"]){   

                        $_SESSION['user']=1;
                        header("location:login.php");
                        exit();
                        }
                        else{
                            echo "<div style='position:absolute; right:230px; top:220px;'><b>WRONG PASSWORD<br>Re Input PASSWORD</b></div>";
                        }
                    }
                    else if($_POST['user']==$credentials2["useradmin"]){
                        if($_POST['pass']==$credentials2["pass"]){  

                        $_SESSION['user']=1;
                        header("location:adminlogin.php");
                        exit();
                        }
                        else{
                            echo "<div style='position:absolute; right:230px; top:220px;'><b>WRONG PASSWORD<br>Re Input PASSWORD</b></div>";
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        echo "<div style='position:absolute; right:230px; top:220px;'><b>WRONG USERNAME<br>Re Input Username</b></div>";
                    }
    }
    ?>
```

Here is the php script of adding users:

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if($_POST['secret']=="060593"){

$user = $_POST['newuser'];
$pass = $_POST['newpass'];
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

    if($connect){
            mysql_select_db("dbreserve",$connect);  
            $query = "INSERT INTO tblru (user,pass) VALUES (\"" . $user . "\",\"" . $pass . "\")";
            if(mysql_query($query)){
                echo "<div style='position:absolute; left:615px; top:645px;'><font color='#FFFFFF'><b>User Successfully Created</b></font></div>";
            } else {
                die ("Failed" . mysql_error()); 
            }
        } else {
                die ("Failed to connect to mysql: " . mysql_error());
    }
}
    }
    ?>
```

and here is the form for adding registered users:
sjdhgsadlgjasldgijsaldfjskldgsaodjfislahdflisdjf;asdjglisadf dont bother asking what i typed i just typed it sa i can make the revisions
        
        
            
            Secret Code:
            
            
            New User:
            
            
            
            New Users Password:

Comment: Please be aware that the mysql extension is [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) and will be removed in future PHP versions. It's suggested to either use [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) or the [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) extension, so your code is future-proof.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
include("conn.php");
$qry=mysql_query("Select * from tblru");
$qry2=mysql_query("Select * from tbladmin");
$credentials=mysql_fetch_assoc($qry);
$credentials2=mysql_fetch_assoc($qry2);
while ($row = $credentials) {
    $user = $row['user'];
    $pass = $row['pass'];
}
if(isset($_POST['login'])){

                if($_POST['user']==$user){
                    if($_POST['pass']==$pass){   

                    $_SESSION['user']=1;
                    header("location:login.php");
                    exit();
                    }
                    else{
                        echo "<div style='position:absolute; right:230px; top:220px;'><b>WRONG PASSWORD<br>Re Input PASSWORD</b></div>";
                    }
                }
                else if($_POST['user']==$credentials2["useradmin"]){
                    if($_POST['pass']==$credentials2["pass"]){  

                    $_SESSION['user']=1;
                    header("location:adminlogin.php");
                    exit();
                    }
                    else{
                        echo "<div style='position:absolute; right:230px; top:220px;'><b>WRONG PASSWORD<br>Re Input PASSWORD</b></div>";
                    }
                }
                else{
                    echo "<div style='position:absolute; right:230px; top:220px;'><b>WRONG USERNAME<br>Re Input Username</b></div>";
                }
}
?>
```

Comment: You should put `mysql_error();` under your second query. See if that comes to anything.

Comment: already done it but the result is still the same, i cant access the admin.php using the other accounts
and it doesnt show any error

Comment: Put a `die();` after the `$credentials2` variable. That should output an error. Copy and paste that error.

Comment: when i used the die, the page went all white, and didnt dislay anything

Comment: So there's no errors. I think what your problem is that you are only validating the `$_POST['user']` against the first array. Hold on real quick.

Comment: This is the situation, it has no errors, but on mysql_query select * from tblru, can you think of another alternative where if a input another account or $_POST['user'] it can validate it in the database, and then validate again the password with $_POST['pass'] so that it can pass the log in process

Comment: You need to provide some more information. Right before that `die();` do a `print_r($credentials);`. Then comment what you get.

Comment: i got this 'Array ( [0] => 2 [userid] => 2 [1] => catalino [user] => catalino [2] => yanos [pass] => yanos )'

Comment: Now change the `print_r($credentials)` to `print_r($credentials2)`

Comment: i got this one 'Array ( [0] => marygrace [useradmin] => marygrace [1] => donato [pass] => donato )' well that credentials2 is the user password combination for the main administrator,

Comment: OK and you said that the regular users are working but not administrative ones?

Comment: nope, this is the situation, let me explain again, i have the credentials2 as my administrative which creates the registered users and shows you the lists of their username and password, i can access the administration, and i can also access the registered user using the combination catalino & yanos, but i cannot open it using other  registered users username and password combination

Comment: wait ill try to post the images

Comment: Ok. But according to the array up there, there is only two records (registered users). `'Array ( [0] => 2 [userid] => 2 [1] => catalino [user] => catalino [2] => yanos [pass] => yanos )` That means there are two records of same username. But as you can see, there is only catalino.

Comment: No need to post pictures. Just create more users. There is only one user and that's with the Username **catalino** and password of **yanos**

Comment: how can i fix this then??

Comment: Well you said you had a register form? Go create some users and then it should work.

Comment: i created 6 new users but it still doesnt appear even if i used the
print_r(credentials); die():

Comment: So you did a `print_r($credentials);` and what did you get back?

Comment: i got thesame
        Array ( [0] => 2 [userid] => 2 [1] => catalino [user] => catalino [2] => yanos [pass] => yanos )
i viewed my database and it has 6 more users, but how can that be that when i print_r it it only displays 1 user

Comment: Are you sure you're not inserting them into the wrong table??

Comment: im pretty sure about that, i checked the database and the table and i got them on where i wanted them, can you think of other way i can retrieve those data, in my database??

Comment: Are you using phpmyadmin? And post your register script on here to.

Comment: i use php,and mysql as database, pure code but i got confused by the time i planned to make registered users, its kinda annoying me, but our professor insisted that in our system i must have registered users

Comment: It's just a way of viewing the database. But post your register script on here, so we can see what's going on there.

Comment: check the script on top, hope you could help me fix this problem, :(

Comment: I dont't know. I can't see a problem??

Comment: even i cant see where the problem is, but its obvious that i can only retrieve 1 data in the database even if i selected them all

Comment: In the login, why don't you try replacing `mysql_fetch_array` with `mysql_fetch_assoc`

Comment: i used this: $credentials=mysql_fetch_assoc($qry);
i got this: Array ( [userid] => 2 [user] => catalino [pass] => yanos )